# Firebase facebook login

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login

I have previously added facebook login to my app which uses firebase.

But recently I wanted to do the same for a new app and I faced a strange issue I cannot solve. So everything is ok until almost the end where I have to add a valid OAuth redirect URI. I copy the one that firebase gives me, but facebook won't accept it saying it's malicious!

Anyone knows what the issue might be?

UPDATE: I gave the url from one of my previous projects and it is accepted! so the url of this new project seems faulty. What do I do? I also noticed that the url of my previous project starts with my project name but this faulty one starts with bionic-biplane which seems weird

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend try FirebaseUI. It includes Facebook authentication and very easy to implement. I remember I also had issues with Facebook auth so I switched to FirebaseUI. Since you use Firebase as a back for your project it might be perfect solution for you.